# Why different styles of fonts are shown separately?

Tags: fonts

In Windows font manager, different styles of a font are shown as a font family. But in some software's (e.g. Chrome) font settings, they shows separately. What causes this? **Is it the matter of metadata?**

Example:

[image: Fonts show separately.]
[image: Fonts shown as font family.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally a matter of "what do you need to know in this context".

Desktop Publishing applications, as well as the OS in general, will show you only the *font family* because that's what's going to matter to you when you're doing DTP: you want to just pick a font, and then be able to tick a box or click a button to select "bold" or "italic", instead of having to highlight your text and the pick the actual font file that should be used for styling.

On the other hand, browsers, and really any typesetting technology where stretches of data get their properties from styling definitions (so that's obviously CSS but also things such as LaTeX or InDesign) need to show all the *font files* that are available for you to use (or, as in InDesign, show you in excruciating detail what the family can do in property panels), because that's what matters: "bold" or "italic" doesn't mean anything unless you first set up the rules that tell the engine which file belongs to that differentiation.

If Chrome only showed you the family name, that would be completely useless, because you would have no idea which variations are even available. You want to know exactly which files exist, so you know which weight/style/variants you can even reliable set up.